# Java: how to create SOAP request?

Tags: java, soap

I have a wsdl and xsd files and want to create SOAP request to web server on python. I have never worked with soap before so my question probably simple but I spend the four hours and havn't found the solution.

I try two ways: low level request and KSOAP2 on Android.

wsdl

```
    <wsdl:message name="<some request>">
    <wsdl:part element="txh:<some request>" name="parameters"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="<some response>">
    <wsdl:part element="txh:<some response>" name="parameters"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

xsd

```
    <xs:element name=""<some request>">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>"<text>"</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="mode" type="response-mode"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="<some response>">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>"<text>"</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="<text>"/>
            <xs:element name="<another text>" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="<name a>" type="xs:int"/>
                        <xs:element name="<name b>" type="xs:int"/>
                        <xs:element name="<name c>" type="xs:int"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Code in Android:

```
private final static String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n" +
                         "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope " +
                         "xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" " +
                         "xmlns:SOAP-ENC=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" " +
                         "xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" " +
                         "xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">" +
                        "<SOAP-ENV:Header>" +
                        "</SOAP-ENV:Header>" +
                        "<SOAP-ENV:Body xmlns:ns1=\"<namespace>\">" +
                        "    <xs:element name=\"<request>\"> " +
                        "<xs:annotation>" +
                            "<xs:documentation>"<text>"</xs:documentation>" +
                        "</xs:annotation>" +
                        "<xs:complexType>" +
                            "<xs:sequence>" +
                                "<xs:element name=\""<text>"\" type=\"response-mode\"/>" +
                            "</xs:sequence>" +
                        "</xs:complexType>" +
                    "</xs:element>" +
                        "</SOAP-ENV:Body>" +
                        "</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";



 public Entity execute(final String body) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Start request ");
    Entity result = new Entity();
    AndroidHttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance(TAG);
    HttpParams params = client.getParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 10000);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 15000);
    HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(params, true);

    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
    post.setParams(params);
    post.setHeader("soapaction", NAMESPACE.concat("/").concat(METHOD));
    post.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset-utf8");
    try {
        String request = createRequest(xml);
        HttpEntity entityToRequest = new StringEntity(request);
        post.setEntity(entityToRequest);
        Log.d(TAG, post.toString());

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        final int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (HttpStatus.SC_OK == status) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            String str = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            Log.d(TAG, str);
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

On this request I get a 500 server code, so I suppose that the issue in my request. Do you think that it is formed well?

Comment: You could have a look at the Apache Axis2 framework, which provides generators and lots of stuff for SOAP based web services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. The soupUI and similar instruments can help to understand a structure of your soap rtequests.

Comment: Your request looks like you're trying to send the xsd XML at the endpoint, rather than a document that complies with the XSD. But as you're found yourself, soapUI is a great tool to copy and paste XML. Try to get to the point where you can paste the soapUI XML into a txt file on the Java side so you dont have all the tedious mucking about escaping quotation marks etc. Your Java program can then read in the txt file at runtime.